# Odd Firefox rendering (css transform)

Tags: firefox, css, rendering, transform

this new CSS3 stuff is so fancy, but the rendering seems to be really inconsistent among browsers (and I'm not even talking about the shadow shape itself)

Here I made an example that looks fabulous in Chrome, but with a jagged border in Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/eBJxV/4/

Note that I've added a box-shadow and it looks like the background color shines through.
For Chrome, there is this workaround with translate3D, is there also something I can do for Firefox?

here's the code you can also see in JSFiddle

```
h1 {
    background-color: #E8501F;
    border-radius: 13px 0 0 13px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    transform: matrix(0.997564, -0.0697565, 0.0697565, 0.997564, 0, 0);
    transform: rotate(-4deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);


    -webkit-transform: matrix(0.997564, -0.0697565, 0.0697565, 0.997564, 0, 0) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);

    margin:10px 0;
    width:100px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Verdana;
    color:#ffffff;
}

body{
background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: used to -moz-transform for old firefox

Comment: Check this for good examples : http://css3please.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with a CSS filter:

```
filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><filter id="gaussian_blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" /></filter></defs></svg>#gaussian_blur');
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBJxV/14/

Note that this info (and more) is convered on a blog post I wrote a while ago on the subject:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**used to this**  for old **Firefox** `-moz`

**As like this**

```
h1 {

    -moz-transform: matrix(0.997564, -0.0697565, 0.0697565, 0.997564, 0, 0) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);

}
```

Comment: Alright, I'll also use vendor prefixes, but this does not solve the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, by adding a border with 1px with, and the same background color.
Then apply box-sizing differently, sot that the border is part of the size.
Then due to padding, had to change the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/eBJxV/19/

```css
h1 {
    background-color: #E8501F;
    border-radius: 13px 0 0 13px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E8501F;
    border-width:1px;
    transform: matrix(0.997564, -0.0697565, 0.0697565, 0.997564, 0, 0);
    transform: rotate(-4deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    
    -webkit-transform: matrix(0.997564, -0.0697565, 0.0697565, 0.997564, 0, 0) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);

    margin:10px 0;
    width:140px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Verdana;
    color:#ffffff;
}

body{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
   <h1>JSFiddle</h1>
   <h1>Shiddle</h1>
```

Comment: Not sure now if it looks exactly same, seems the border 1px did move the title.. oh well - or my eyes are playing tricks :D.

Comment: This seems to have the same distorted, jagged borders on the font as your original question